# facebook sharer.php error chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome

I am using the sharer button inside a facebook app. It works in all browsers except Chrome.
docs.google.com/open?id=0B4wxEQ6Do659WmcwdkN5VlFDZ2s

I check tools->javascript console and I see that I have a warning:

> [blocked] The page at https://mywebsite.com ran insecure content
>   from http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share.

The code used in this button is:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="http://mywebsite.com" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Googled it, Stackoverflowed it but nothing helpful out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, your site is using `https` protocol, but since that script is on http, chrome thinks this is a security issue.

Use https version of the file which is located at: **https://facebook.com/connect.php/js/FB.Share**

and you should be fine.